# New kind of Select_list found and don't know how to write the code for that

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-classic

I have written code for select list this way b.select_list(:id,'something').select 'something' but I don't how know how to write a code for given below select list, Can anyone help me to write the code to select from this select_list

```
<md-select tabindex="0" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" role="listbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-expanded="false" aria-invalid="true" aria-multiselectable="false" aria-required="true" aria-owns="select_container_5" aria-label="Gender" ng-model="user.gender" name="gender" required=""><md-select-value class="_md-select-value _md-select-placeholder" id="select_value_label_0"><span>Gender</span><span class="_md-select-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span></md-select-value><div class="_md-select-menu-container" id="select_container_5" aria-hidden="true"><md-select-menu class="ng-scope"><md-content>
                            <md-option tabindex="0" class="md-ink-ripple" id="select_option_3" role="option" aria-selected="false" value="Male"><div class="_md-text">Male</div></md-option>
                            <md-option tabindex="0" class="md-ink-ripple" id="select_option_4" role="option" aria-selected="false" value="Female"><div class="_md-text">Female</div></md-option>
                            </md-content></md-select-menu></div></md-select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the element tag, `md-select`, it looks like this [select list is created by Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/select). It is not a `select` element, which means you cannot use the usual `select_list` method. Instead, you need to manually interact with it. This involves:

1. Clicking the select list to open the list of options
2. Clicking one of the options

The following code will select an option by value. You could use a different locator as needed:

```
# Open the dropdown
browser.element(tag_name: 'md-select', name: 'gender').click

# Select an option (by value)
browser.element(tag_name: 'md-option', value: 'Female').when_present.click
```

A couple of notes:

- As `md-select` is not a standard element, you need to locate it using the generic `element` method.
- Make sure to use `when_present` (or another wait method) to ensure the options are displayed before selecting.

Comment: Thank you very much Justin Ko, This is really fantastic, it works fine.

Comment: hi, `<md-option tabindex="0" class="ng-scope md-ink-ripple" id="select_option_140" role="option" aria-checked="true" aria-selected="true" value="1000010" selected="selected" ng-repeat="m in masterData.Makes" ng-value="m.Id"><div class="_md-text ng-binding">Chery</div><div class="md-ripple-container"></div></md-option>`
Hi In the above select_list I tried to click using the below code 

`browser.element(tag_name: 'md-option', text: 'Chery').when_present.click`

But it's not working, what might be the problem?

Comment: There are quite a number of possible reasons. You'll need to be more specific about what is/isn't working and how to reproduce the problem. Does the code work for selecting other options in that dropdown? Is the problem specific to the one dropdown or all of the ones in your application?

Comment: As you said `b.element(tag_name: 'md-select', id: 'select_41').click


b.element(tag_name: 'md-option', text: 'Single').when_present.click`

This one works,but

`b.element(tag_name: 'md-select', id: 'no-claim-discount').click

b.element(tag_name: 'md-option', text: '10%').when_present.click`

This one doesn't work. What might be the reason, how could I resolve this problem? 

But second clicks the corresponding element, but element is not visible(choosing is not done) after the click operation.

Comment: What are the differences (ex how they appear, what actions they trigger or are triggered by) between the dropdowns? Once you know the differences, you can debug to figure out what is wrong. Without an example, I am not sure there is much more I can help with.

Comment: First option
`<md-option tabindex="0" class="ng-scope md-ink-ripple" id="select_option_206" role="option" aria-checked="true" aria-selected="false" ng-repeat="m in masterData.MaritalStatuses" ng-value="m.Id" value="2"><div class="_md-text ng-binding">Married</div><div class="md-ripple-container"></div></md-option>`
Second Option
`<md-option tabindex="0" class="ng-scope md-ink-ripple" id="select_option_207" role="option" aria-checked="true" aria-selected="false" ng-repeat="m in masterData.Ncds" ng-value="m.Id" value="10002"><div class="_md-text ng-binding">0%</div></md-option>`

Comment: In the above comment I have mentioned two options which I tried to click, I don't find any difference, Do you find any?

Comment: The markup for the two is different, though unlikely to matter. Given that you said Watir is clicking both options, but just failing to trigger the selection, the problem is likely the related JavaScript. You'll probably want to look into that - ie what events need to be fired and whether Watir is triggering them.

Comment: " what events need to be fired and whether Watir is triggering them" How would I know what events needs to be fired? In what way?

Comment: You would have to dig into the JavaScript.

Comment: I resolved the problem, The problem is in the first line of code which clicks and opens the list, I used another the wrong one, Now I have used the right id to open the list, it works fine, So there is not problem in this code `browser.element(tag_name: 'md-option', text: 'Chery').when_present.click`